# Can partial derivatives be expressed as a fraction?

Tags: proof-verification, partial-derivative

Let $a = bc$. Then $b = a/c$. From the first equation, we also have $\frac{\partial a}{\partial c} = b$. Equating, $\frac{\partial a}{\partial c} = b = a/c$, or $\frac{\partial a}{\partial c} = a/c$, and any partial derivative can be expressed a fraction of its constituents.

Is there something wrong with this proof? If so, what? This looks like such a simplification that I'm convinced it must be wrong, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: It won't always hold that $\frac{\partial a}{\partial c} = a/c$. For example, try with $a = bc^{2}$.

Comment: Not true in general.. this is just because $a$ happens to be a linear function of $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assumed that $a$ is a scalar multiple of $c$ and therefore (assuming both are differentiable) $a'$ is going to be the same scalar multiple of $c'$ by elementary properties of derivatives. It's not a powerful result, because you put some pretty extreme restrictions on $a$ and $c$, namely that they are scalar multiples.

Comment: Are you saying that there's an assumption that $b$ is a scalar in the proof? If so, where'd that enter the proof? It seems to me that just setting $a=bc$, there's no constraint on all three of $a$, $b$ and $c$ (other than the relation).

Comment: Well you took a partial with respect to $c$ right? So $b$ is a constant, otherwise you're statement that  $\frac{\partial a}{\partial c}=b$ is false, right there you have assumed $b$ is a constant.

Comment: Doesn't this only assume that $b$ is independent of $c$ (since it's a partial derivative not full derivative)?

Comment: But if its independent of $c$, then its not changing at all in the context of this problem, and is therefore constant correct?

Comment: Basically, you should have done product rule when taking the derivative of the product, and assuming you did, the only way you got what you did is if $\frac{\partial b}{\partial c}=0$, namely that it is a constant with respect to $c$